# Multivariete Regression Error "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'"

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, multivariate-testing

I'm trying to run a multivariate linear regression but I'm getting an error when trying to get the coefficients of the regression model.

The error I'm getting is this:
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import seaborn as seabornInstance 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import metrics
%matplotlib inline

# Main files
dataset = pd.read_csv('namaste_econ_model.csv')
dataset.shape
dataset.describe()
dataset.isnull().any()

#Dividing data into "attributes" and "labels". X variable contains all the attributes and y variable contains labels.

X = dataset[['Read?', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6' , 'x7','x8','x9','x10','x11','x12','x13','x14','x15','x16','x17','x18','x19','x20','x21','x22','x23','x24','x25','x26','x27','x28','x29','x30','x31','x32','x33','x34','x35','x36','x37','x38','x39','x40','x41','x42','x43','x44','x45','x46','x47']].values
y = dataset['Change in Profit (BP)'].values
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
plt.tight_layout()
seabornInstance.distplot(dataset['Change in Profit (BP)'])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
regressor = LinearRegression()  
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
coeff_df = pd.DataFrame(regressor.coef_, X.columns, columns=['Coefficient'])  
coeff_df
```

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-67-773b9f78bc01>", line 14, in <module>
    coeff_df = pd.DataFrame(regressor.coef_, X.columns, columns=['Coefficient'])

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

Any help on this will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Always give full trace back of error. Give line number at least. It will help debug.

Comment: Your `X` and `Y` are numpy arrays, not dataframes. Your error is probably in `coeff_df`. Remove the `.values` and give it a try.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource. However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest solution attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: Not clear with the end goal, do you want to output the coefficients of each column??

Comment: @Poojan sorry about that. I just edited the post. Thanks for the support!

Comment: Hi @abheet22, yes that's correct, I'd like to get the coefficients of each column. Thank you so much for the support.

Comment: Hi @Danny, I tried doing that but then I get the same coefficient for all of the X variables. Here's a screenshot of the output https://prnt.sc/paxla0

Comment: Could you print `regressor.coef_`?

Comment: @Danny of course, here's the output: https://prnt.sc/paxny0 .

Comment: It looks like your regressor is picking up only the first column which means it is the most important variable and looks like it's the only variable that it's predicting on. There could be data leakage through that variable? But that's another issue. You can post it in [Data Science Stack](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/). Your coding issue if fixed, right?

Comment: That is correct, I've posted in Data Science Stack, thank you so much Danny! Here's the link in case anyone wants to follow the thread: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/60770/multivariate-regression-error-attributeerror-numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-att

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the exact same thing, removing the .values from the X variable on line 18 worked for me!

Comment: this should be a comment and not an answer